# Android manually restore fragments programatically when they are added to custom views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, lifecycle

I'm saving my fragments data and whatever i need to restore them in fragments "onSaveInstanceState" and activities "onSaveInstanceState"

I'm not using any xml layouts and everything is created with code.
as i can see there is a "android:support:fragments" key with FragmentManagerState type in "Bundle savedInstanceState" when activity is restored.

but i don't know how to use it to restore fragments history

here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends NemoActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ModelUser.getCurrentUser(getApplicationContext());
    ModelUser.getCurrentUser().Authenticate();

    mRootLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.nemoui_activity_startup_background));

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d("nemo", "saved state");
    } else {
        if (Settings.getInstance().isFirstRun()) {
            ShowWelcomeScreen();
        } else {
            ShowFragment(new MainMenuFragment(), "fullscreen", "main-menu", null);
        }
    }
} ......
```

and root activity:

```
public class NemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected FrameLayout   mRootLayout;
protected HashMap<String, FragmentPlaceholder> mPlaceholderTagMap = new HashMap<>();
protected HashMap<String, FragmentPlaceholder> mFragmentTagMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mRootLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    mRootLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(mRootLayout);
}
```

and here is how i add/replace fragments

```
....
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(root.getFragmentRootResourceID(), fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commit();
....
```

my fragments are added to a custom subclass of "FrameLayout" (which does not save any bundle data) and is 3 levels deep

Comment: check out the method `addToBackStack()` of `FragmentManager` API

Comment: i'm already adding fragments to backstack, but nothing is shown when i rotate the device

Comment: Mybad, `addToBackStack ()` is in `FragmentTransaction`, not `FragmentManager`. You need to pop it from the back stack using `FragmentManager` APIs